# Use JSON to print in readable format PHP & Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i work on project to get data from db and present / show it in andriod application 
i work on php& mysql

in php file i write this

```
<?php

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $x = $row;


 $json = json_encode($x, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

the code show as the following
its readable but no breaks when i run it on browser
show like this

```
{"data":{"sender":"Jhon Andrew","recipient":"Someone OverThe Internet","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."}}
```

i want it to show like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "sender":"Jhon Andrew",
        "recipient":"Someone OverThe Internet",
        "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    }
}
```

why when i run the code in browser show in readable format but no breaks
and it will show in andriod arranged or not ?

Comment: Browsers don't render newlines or multiple spaces.  Wwrap in `<pre>` tags or use `highlight_string()`

Comment: Does the JSON is used by the application on Android, or just displayed?

Comment: it's the same code

Comment: @ Syscall  its run when i use crtl+u

Comment: but when i use  $json = json_encode($tem,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); not run

Comment: i will use json in andriod to show date saved in database

Comment: Did you even read the first comment?

Comment: @ Syscall  , my code php is to connect betwwen mysql and andriod so if data show in browser without space when i use "json_unescaped_unicode ) it will no problem and it will show arranged in andriod ?

Comment: @ AbraCadaver i read it right now but i dont know where i show write <pre> or highlight_string

Comment: `$json = json_encode($tem, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` should actually be `$json = json_encode($tem, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: `highlight_string($json);` or `echo "<pre>$json</pre>";`  highlight actually transforms the string to render properly, the `pre` tag means pre-formatted so it will render the newlines and spaces.

Comment: it work for me too , and it will show in andriod arranged @ AbraCadaver

Comment: @AbraCadaver I've suggested that, because I thought that changing the output will fails the application on Android (because the output will not be a valid JSON otherwise).

Comment: @Syscall can u told me anyway will be vaild in showing in andriod application $json = json_encode($tem, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);, or highlight_string($json);

Comment: Please don't gut your question like that. The answer makes no sense with all of that content removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `if`. The same URL, but with a parameter for to display on the web.

Let suppose the URL of the JSON is http://example.com/service.php that returns a valid JSON. You could use a parameter to change the display, by example http://example.com/service.php?view

Then, in your code :

```
if (isset($_GET['view'])) {
    highlight_string($json) ; // As @AbraCadaver suggested
} else {
    echo $json ; // Valid JSON for the service.
}
```

Comment: my php file all job to show data saved in database in andriod aplication will not insert any information

Comment: so can i use this $json = json_encode($tem, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

Comment: using if will be only with 
@AbraCadaver suggested

Comment: @karimsemsssm Yes, I think.

Answer (score 0):

use this [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en) in chrome to get desired and formatted output

[image]

> it will show in andriod arranged or not ?

if you just want to display it in a `TextView` for example, it will not be displayed as you want. but it will be wrapped.